# Как посчитать количество ссылок на изображения, аудио и видео на странице?

Tags: python, поиск-библиотек

Допустим у меня есть текст простой веб страницы.
Есть ли какие нибудь библиотеки для подсчета количество ссылок на изображения, аудио, видео на странице?

Comment: Используйте обычные библиотеки для парсинга либо re

Answer (score 1, accepted):

есть библиотека [beautiful soup 4](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/), lспециально для поиска чего-бы то ни было на странице, в интернете вы можете найти примеры работы с ней, орт себя скажу: в bs4 есть методы для поиска какого бы ни было тега на странице, идите от этого, если вам нужно найти все изображения то такой код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = 'вот сюда текст вашего документа'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

res = soup.find_all('img')
```

вернет что-то типа

```
[<img class="sister" src="http://example.com/tillie/image.jpg" id="link3">
<img class="sister" src="http://example.com/tillie/image123.jpg" id="link3">] 

#в общем все теги img со всеми их параметрами, чтобы получить ссылку на файл (атрибут src):

for link in res:
    print(link.get('src'))

# http://example.com/tillie/image.jpg
# http://example.com/tillie/image123.jpg
```

так же, если у вас есть на пример ссылки на какие-то файлы на пример в тегах `a`,  [вот тут](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) можно посмотреть примеры...